# a4j command button not working under popup panel

Tags: richfaces, ajax4jsf, popuppanel

I want to add a popup panel. In this panel there is a close button. On this button click a method should be invoked and popup should get hide. I have tried below code but not working kindly help me with this. Here settingPopUpClose is a method and okPopupStatus is a bean. It is displaying error: settingPopUpClose  is not a property.

```
<rich:popupPanel id="okcontactpopup" width="450" height="50"
domElementAttachment="form">
<f:facet name="header">
</f:facet>
<f:facet name="controls">
    <h:panelGroup>

        <a4j:commandButton value="Close"
            actionListener="#{staffMsgingHccDiscoHandler.settingPopUpClose}"
            oncomplete="if(#{not empty staffMsgingHccDiscoHandler.hccDiscoBean.okPopupStatus}) #{rich:component('okcontactpopup')}.hide();" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</f:facet>
<h:panelGrid>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText
                value="#{staffMsgingHccDiscoHandler.hccDiscoBean.okPopup}"
                id="okpopup" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: I am not able to scroll my code. Are you guys able to?

Comment: Can you show the `staffMsgingHccDiscoHandler` bean? (The annotations and the `settingPopUpClose` would be enough) And yes, we can scroll it.

Comment: Is the popup in the form?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @makhiel and @emil for your reply. But i solved the problem.

```
<a4j:commandButton value="CLOSE" action="#{staffMsgingHccDiscoHandler.settingPopUpClose}" oncomplete=" #{rich:component('okcontactpopup')}.hide();" />
```

I did not enclosed my richface popup inside form. This worked fine for me.